# Displaying the correct number of visible items in a grid

Tags: angular, grid, primeng

I have a grid written in angular 2 that uses pagination, each page should have 5 rows. I want it to display the number of items that are currently on display like 'Showing 1-5 users of 7 in total' on the first page and 'Showing 6-7 users of 7 in total' in the 2nd page but i am not too sure how to do it.

[image]

Comment: use items-per-page option like items-per-page (Defaults: 10) : Maximum number of items per page. A value less than one indicates all items on one page.

Comment: hi, thanks for posting. I have the max items per page set to 5, but its showing the number of items per page where i have the issue.

Comment: Can you share your code please ?